# Apache virtualhost always to host earlier inline

Tags: apache, ssl

The host I have besides the default SSL are `entis.bla.nl` and `test.bla.nl` when going to `test.bla.nl` the page served is from `entis.bla.nl`. If I visit the server by IP I get the default SSL host which should be expected as you can see bellow.

```
  wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
    *:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
             default server bla.colo.bla.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:2)
             port 443 namevhost bla.colo.bla.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:2)
             port 443 namevhost entis.bla.nl (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/live-entis:19)
             port 443 namevhost test.bla.nl (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test-entis:21)
```

Configuration of entis.bla.nl:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName entis.bla.nl
        DocumentRoot /var/www/live/web

    <Directory /var/www/live/web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine On

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/apache-ssl/apache.pem

        ServerName entis.bla.nl
        DocumentRoot /var/www/live/web

    <Directory /var/www/live/web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Configuration of test:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.bla.nl
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test/web

    <Directory /var/www/test/web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/test-error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine On

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/apache-ssl/apache.pem

        ServerName test.bla.nl
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test/web

    <Directory /var/www/test/web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/test-error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

**Update**
Found this in the error.log. Not sure if it is directly related because the non-ssl configuration has the same issue as the ssl configuration.

```
[Tue Oct 01 13:06:07 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Oct 01 13:06:08 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Oct 01 13:06:08 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Oct 01 13:06:08 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: Strange. According to http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts this should work -- of course your users will receive certificate errors if you're not using a wildcard cerficate for `*.bla.nl` -- but as you say, your non-SSL configuration has the same issue.

Comment: Do you also have a `NameVirtualHost *:80` in your config? Tip: Apache 2.4 makes this easier by removing this silly directive completely.

Comment: OK, it seems Apache is doing as documented and using the *first* virtual host to setup the SSL connection, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the documentation at http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts closer, and the important bit is (emphasis mine):

> In reality, Apache will allow you to configure name-based SSL virtual
>   hosts, *but it will always use the configuration from the first-listed
>   virtual host* (on the selected IP address and port) to setup the
>   encryption layer*. In certain specific circumstances, it is acceptable
>   to use a single SSL configuration for several virtual hosts. In
>   particular, this will work if the SSL certificate applies to all the
>   virtual hosts. For example, this will work if:
>
> All the VirtualHosts are within the same domain, eg: one.example.com and two.example.com.
>
> You have a wildcard SSL certificate for that domain (one where the Common Name begins with an asterix: i.e *.example.com)